# VS2019 attempting to load a dll that no longer exists

Tags: c#

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
- Version 16.6.1
- VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.1+30128.74
- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Version 4.8.03761
- Installed Version: Community
- Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA486
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

VS is attempting to load a dll (eesPhotography.dll) that no longer exits.
I'm getting the following message in the Assembly Binding Log Viewer:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (6/10/2020 @ 5:40:57 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\Software\EES\eesPhotography\bin\x64\Debug\eesPhotography.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = eesPhotography, Version=1.0.0.456, Culture=neutral
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: eesPhotography, Version=1.0.0.456, Culture=neutral | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Software/EES/eesPhotography/bin/x64/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = eesPhotography.exe
Calling assembly : PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Software\EES\eesPhotography\bin\x64\Debug\eesPhotography.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Software/EES/eesPhotography/bin/x64/Debug/eesPhotography.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Software/EES/eesPhotography/bin/x64/Debug/eesPhotography/eesPhotography.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Software/EES/eesPhotography/bin/x64/Debug/eesPhotography.EXE.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: D:\Software\EES\eesPhotography\bin\x64\Debug\eesPhotography.exe
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: eesPhotography, Version=1.0.1.31820, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=18ac120590811ed0
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: `VS is attempting to load a dll` That doesn't just happen out of the blues. There must be a reference somewhere in your configuration and/or project that causes VS to try and load that dll. Guessing what/where that is would require that you provide a lot more details.

Comment: Long ago and far away there was a dll with that name. It was removed years ago.  Everything was working until I installed a certificate. (My apologies for not mentioning that earlier). I will supply any information you need. I have been going through the project from top to bottom and can find no reference to the dll.

Comment: Don't know that the problem is with a dll. The log indicates that the .exe assembly was located, but failed to load because `Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number`.

Comment: Dxiv- what would that indicate? I've searched the internet but none of the solutions have worked.

Comment: Sounds like you have a reference somewhere to `v1.0.0.456` but the version found on disk is `v1.0.1.31820`.

Comment: Do you know where I can access the DisplayName and the Assembly Name? I'm at a loss...

Comment: Don't know, but running a text search might find something in a project file and/or properties file.

Comment: I found the assembly reference in AssemblyInfo.cs. I changed it to match the other version and it's working. But I suspect I'm doing something wrong. More research. But thanks for your help. At least I have a starting point :)

Comment: For future reference: Files AssemblyInfo.cs  reference: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.1")]  and file .csproj reference: <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2.1</AssemblyVersion> must match.